# Unit Test React JSX ES6

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, karma-runner

I'm using **React**, **JSX**, **ES6** and **Karma**.

Someone knows what is wrong in my code?

I'm trying to pass this test with [Karma-Runner](https://karma-runner.github.io/) but something is wrong:

```
let React = require("react");
let TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
let expect = require("expect");

/* global describe */
/* global it */
describe("Header", function () {
  it("renders without problems", function () {
    let component = <Header/>;
    let header = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component);

    expect(header).toExist();
  });
});
```

After `$ karma start` command, this is the error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/aralroca/react-es6-boilerplate/app/tests/components/header.test.js: Unexpected token (9:20)
   7 | describe("Header", function () {
   8 |   it("renders without problems", function () {
>  9 |     let component = <Header/>;
     |                     ^
  10 |     let header = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component);
  11 | 
  12 |     expect(header).toExist();
```

Thank you so much.

---

## Edited

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: [ process.env.CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION ? "Firefox" : "Chrome" ],
    files: [
      "tests.bundle.js"
    ],
    frameworks: ["chai", "mocha"],
    plugins: [
      "karma-chrome-launcher",
      "karma-chai",
      "karma-mocha",
      "karma-sourcemap-loader",
      "karma-webpack"
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      "tests.bundle.js": ["webpack", "sourcemap"]
    },
    reporters: ["dots"],
    singleRun: true,
    webpack: {
      devtool: "inline-source-map",
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            test: /\.jsx?$/
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JSX in tests you need to wire up the [karma-babel-preprocessor](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor).

This will run babel to transpile the tests before execution.  Otherwise, when karma runs tests, the ES6 or JSX syntax will cause errors.

Comment: I installed and added in `karma.conf.js` like a "plugin". But nothing... The same error...

Comment: Can you post your `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: Added :) Thank you @Davin Tryon